# Angular 1.5.0-beta.0: angular.module(...).component is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use `Angular 1.5.0-beta.0` which I have installed from `npm`.

According to [some guides](http://toddmotto.com/exploring-the-angular-1-5-component-method/) - we can now create a component using `module.component` instead of the old fashion `module.directive`.

This is the component code:

```
 export default angular.module('app.components.header', [])
  .component('dashboardHeader', {
      controller: 'HeaderCtrl as headerCtrl',
      template:  `This is test.`
  })

;
```

My html is:

```
<body>
    <dashboard-header></dashboard-header>
    <div ui-view="content">
</body>
```

I'm getting:

```
angular.module(...).component is not a function
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: The component() function is listed in the documentation of the latest snapshot (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#component), but not in the documentation of beta1 (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-beta.1/docs/api/ng/type/angular.Module) or beta0 (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-beta.0/docs/api/ng/type/angular.Module). So it's safe to assume that this new feature is not in beta0.

Comment: @JBNizet at least now, it's also listed under the 1.5.0v: https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/docs/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider#component

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue  did a 
`bower install angular` it still gave the same error ,
Finally I updated the version of angular.js in script src tag and it worked .

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: about `bower install angular`: In bower.json did you updated the version to latest? "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.5.x"
  },

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing wrong with your code. Install the stable release of angular 1.5. I had the same problem and then deleted angular and installed it with:

```
bower install angular
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not using old version of Angular JS CDN

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for **meteor js** (AngularJs with MeteorJs) .
We need to update the angularjs version.In my case I **updated 1.4.8 to 1.5.3** then restarted the meteor server, error solved.

Command to update angular js(**In case of meteor**)

**meteor update angular:angular** - this will update the angularjs to the latest version available.